# Zend Framework Script Tag <?=

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm just introducing myself to ZF after about a year of OO-PHP experience.  The book I've started with uses:

```
<?=
```

in places instead of

```
<?php echo
```

The author seems pretty confident that this will output the data, instead of the actual code, however, it doesn't seem to be working for me, as I've had to use the normal method instead.

Has anyone used the former instead of the latter succesfully? Any advice on configuration etc... that might cause this to break for me?  Have installed ZF 1.11.11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `<?=` should work fine:

Do note, however, that **before PHP 5.4.0**, `short_open_tag` must be `On` in php.ini for that to work:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Good luck!

Comment: Figured it had something to do with my environment. Haven't even looked at short tags since my early days.  Isn't it considered taboo to use these?

Comment: Not so much taboo, but there is a possibility of confusion with xml tags which open the same. Also, if you are writing code for distribution you can't guarantee that `<?` will work on the user's server as `short open tags` may be turned off. If you are writing code for your own server and you have full control over the environment, then its your call. It does seem to be on of those 'religion' things though, like spaces/tabs emacs/vim :) Personally I'm in the 'short open tags are evil' camp, but if you want to use them and be damned feel free :)

Comment: Thanks Luke, was searching everywhere for the solution and found it here. Dont know why it was set to Off by default! One small configuration can easily waste 3 hours of development time!